# Kusto Query - Get a list all Security Recommendations groupedby Resource Groups

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api, kql, azure-defender

Kusto Query - Get a list all Security Recommendations groupedby Resource Groups, via Azure Graph Explorer.

Link the types :  type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups' and type == 'microsoft.security/assessments'

Get a report with : subscriptionName, resourceGroup, resource type, tags.owner, recommendationName, recommendationSeverity, description, remediationDescription,portalLink.

Comment: please share the query which you have tried

Comment: I intend to join the output of these two:

resourcecontainers
| where type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions' 
| project subscriptionId, subscriptionName = name 
| join (resourcecontainers 
    | where type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups') 
    on subscriptionId 
| project subscriptionName, resourceGroup, tags.owner
| order by resourceGroup asc

Comment: And:

securityresources
| where type == 'microsoft.security/assessments'
| extend resourceId=id,
    source=properties.resourceDetails.Source,
 recommendationName=properties.displayName,
 description=properties.metadata.description,
 remediationDescription=properties.metadata.remediationDescription,
 recommendationSeverity=properties.metadata.severity,
 portalLink=properties.links.azurePortal
| project source,recommendationName, recommendationSeverity, description, remediationDescription,portalLink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the tags of a resource, you need to join with the `resources` table. For the subscription name you need the `resourcecontainers` table. This should work:

```sql
securityresources 
| where type == 'microsoft.security/assessments' 
| join kind=leftouter  (resourcecontainers 
            | where type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions'
            | project subscriptionId, subscription=name)
        on subscriptionId
| extend resourceId = tolower(tostring(properties.resourceDetails.ResourceId))
| join kind=leftouter  (resources | project resourceId=tolower(id), rtags=tags, resourceName=name) on resourceId
| project 
    subscription,
    resourceGroup,
    resourceType=tostring(properties.resourceDetails.ResourceType), 
    recommendationName=properties.displayName, 
    description=properties.metadata.description, 
    remediationDescription=properties.metadata.remediationDescription, 
    recommendationSeverity=properties.metadata.severity, 
    portalLink=properties.links.azurePortal,
    resourceId,
    resourceName,
    owner=rtags.owner
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. However, the query does not work, the outcome I get from running the query you shared is : No Result

Comment: @EdwinOrina thats odd, I checked it agains my recommendations. I've updated my answer to use outer joins, what result does that give you?

Comment: Looks good! However, it also brings recommendations for resourcetype subscription. I don't know if this is accurate, what's your thought on this? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, well, those might be of interest from a security perspective, like "Subscriptions should have a contact email address for security issues" is one of those subscription level recommendations.

Comment: Under resourceid, what do i do such that it shows the resource name only? Thank you.

Comment: @EdwinOrina I've modified the join to the resources to include the resource name, see updated answer

Comment: Hello @Peter Bons, I am trying to add tag information to the below query on Registries. I'd appreciate your assistance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77111429/unable-to-add-tag-information-to-the-below-query-on-container-information