# Unable to add tag information to the below Query on Container information:

Tags: azure, containers, azure-log-analytics-workspace

```
securityresources
 | where type == 'microsoft.security/assessments/subassessments'
 | where id matches regex  '(.+?)/providers/Microsoft.Security/assessments/dbd0cb49-b563-45e7-9724-889e799fa648/'
 | parse id with  registryResourceId '/providers/Microsoft.Security/assessments/' *
 | parse registryResourceId with  * "/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/" registryName
 | extend imageDigest = tostring(properties.additionalData.imageDigest)
 | extend repository = tostring(properties.additionalData.repositoryName)
 | extend scanFindingSeverity = tostring(properties.status.severity), scanStatus = tostring(properties.status.code)
 | summarize scanFindingSeverityCount = count() by scanFindingSeverity, scanStatus, registryResourceId, registryName, repository, imageDigest
 | summarize severitySummary = make_bag(pack(scanFindingSeverity, scanFindingSeverityCount)) by registryResourceId, registryName, repository, imageDigest, scanStatus
 | sort by scanStatus desc
```

To add a Tags column in the query output.

Comment: You can add it using `extend` operator. Did you try using it? @Edwin Orina

Comment: Thank you @jahvani, Kindly share the new query with that addition. Thank you.

Comment: Updated it in the answer. Please check. @Edwin Orina

Answer (score 0):

> To add a Tags column in the query output: -

You need to use [`extend`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/extendoperator) operator to add a column **"Tags"** to the output.
*I modified your code as below:*

```bash
securityresources
 | where type == 'microsoft.security/assessments/subassessments'
 | where id matches regex  '(.+?)/providers/Microsoft.Security/assessments/dbd0cb49-b563-45e7-9724-889e799fa648/'
 | parse id with  registryResourceId '/providers/Microsoft.Security/assessments/' *
 | parse registryResourceId with  * "/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/" registryName
 | extend imageDigest = tostring(properties.additionalData.imageDigest)
 | extend repository = tostring(properties.additionalData.repositoryName)
 | extend scanFindingSeverity = tostring(properties.status.severity), scanStatus = tostring(properties.status.code)
 | extend Tags = "created"
 | summarize scanFindingSeverityCount = count() by scanFindingSeverity, scanStatus, registryResourceId, registryName, repository, imageDigest, Tags
 | summarize severitySummary = make_bag(pack(scanFindingSeverity, scanFindingSeverityCount)) by registryResourceId, registryName, repository, imageDigest, scanStatus, Tags
 | sort by scanStatus desc
```

Update:

```bash
 | mvexpand tags
 | extend tagKey = tostring(bag_keys(tags)[0])
 | extend tagValue = tostring(tags[tagKey])
```

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: I would like it to display the tag name already applied to the containers. The above will append created on all containers.

Comment: Are you trying to display the existed values? @EdwinOrina

Comment: Yes @Jahnavi. I already have tagged containers.

Comment: I've provided an update in the answer. Can you check if it works. @EdwinOrina

Comment: And also check [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-list-all-tags-and-their-values-in-azure/) once. @EdwinOrina

Comment: HI @Jahnavi, no it is not working. It just gives null on the tag column

Comment: Did you check tag values are present for the security resources? @EdwinOrina

Comment: Were you able to work on it.@EdwinOrina

Comment: Hi @Jahnavi,it did not work.

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the tags for the filtered container registry resources? @EdwinOrina