Azure resource graph KQL Join
I have two queries and would like to join them.  One of the queries already has a join so I'm getting confused on the process.  At the end I need a complete security report that will show all the main parts.  I need to include a specific resource tag and I'm trying to get Subscription rather than the ID, along with resource and resource group.
KQL:
SecurityResources
| where type == 'microsoft.security/assessments'
| extend resourceId=id,
  recommendationId=name,
  recommendationName=properties.displayName,
  source=properties.resourceDetails.Source,
  recommendationState=properties.status.code,
  description=properties.metadata.description,
  assessmentType=properties.metadata.assessmentType,
  remediationDescription=properties.metadata.remediationDescription,
  policyDefinitionId=properties.metadata.policyDefinitionId,
  implementationEffort=properties.metadata.implementationEffort,
  recommendationSeverity=properties.metadata.severity,
  category=properties.metadata.categories,
  userImpact=properties.metadata.userImpact,
  threats=properties.metadata.threats,
  portalLink=properties.links.azurePortal
| project tenantId, subscriptionId, resourceId, recommendationName, recommendationId, recommendationState, recommendationSeverity, description, remediationDescription, assessmentType, policyDefinitionId, implementationEffort, userImpact, category, threats, source, portalLink

Join KQL:
resourcecontainers
| where type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions' 
| project subscriptionId, subscriptionName = name 
| join (resourcecontainers 
    | where type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups') 
    on subscriptionId 
| project subscriptionName, resourceGroup, tags.SystemID

Hopefully this is enough information.  I'm trying to use copilot in vs code but keep getting no where.
Here is what I tried:
// List Microsoft Defender recommendations for security assessment and include resource tags that have SystemID.
SecurityResources
| where type == 'microsoft.security/assessments'
| extend resourceId=id,
  recommendationId=name,
  recommendationName=properties.displayName,
  source=properties.resourceDetails.Source,
  recommendationState=properties.status.code,
  description=properties.metadata.description,
  assessmentType=properties.metadata.assessmentType,
  remediationDescription=properties.metadata.remediationDescription,
  policyDefinitionId=properties.metadata.policyDefinitionId,
  implementationEffort=properties.metadata.implementationEffort,
  recommendationSeverity=properties.metadata.severity,
  category=properties.metadata.categories,
  userImpact=properties.metadata.userImpact,
  threats=properties.metadata.threats,
  portalLink=properties.links.azurePortal
| project tenantId, subscriptionId, resourceId, recommendationName, recommendationId, recommendationState, recommendationSeverity, description, remediationDescription, assessmentType, policyDefinitionId, implementationEffort, userImpact, category, threats, source, portalLink
| join kind=leftouter (
    resourcecontainers
    | where type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions'
    | project subscriptionId, subscriptionName = name
    | join kind=leftouter (
        resourcecontainers
        | where type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups'
    ) on subscriptionId
    | project subscriptionId, subscriptionName, resourceGroup, systemID = tostring(tags.SystemID)
    | project subscriptionId, subscriptionName, resourceGroup, systemID = tostring(tags.SystemID)
) on subscriptionId
| project tenantId, subscriptionId, subscriptionName, resourceId, recommendationName, recommendationId, recommendationState, recommendationSeverity, description, remediationDescription, assessmentType, policyDefinitionId, implementationEffort, userImpact, category, threats, source, portalLink, systemID


This will get me started:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76960691/kusto-query-get-a-list-all-security-recommendations-groupedby-resource-groups?rq=2

Could you please share any errors if you are facing with?

Balaji I was able to fix my code.  Cheers

I was able to correct:
securityresources 
| where type == 'microsoft.security/assessments' 
| join kind=leftouter  (resourcecontainers 
            | where type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions'
            | project subscriptionId, subscription=name)
        on subscriptionId
| extend resourceId = tolower(tostring(properties.resourceDetails.ResourceId))
| join kind=leftouter  (resources | project resourceId=tolower(id), rtags=tags.SystemID, resourceName=name) on resourceId
| project 
    subscription,
    resourceGroup,
    resourceType=tostring(properties.resourceDetails.ResourceType), 
    recommendationName=properties.displayName, 
    description=properties.metadata.description, 
    remediationDescription=properties.metadata.remediationDescription, 
    recommendationSeverity=properties.metadata.severity, 
    portalLink=properties.links.azurePortal,
    resourceId,
    resourceName,
    SystemID=rtags
    ```

